# Apache PDFBox - PAGE LENGTH

Tags: pdf, inputstream, pdfbox

I'm using the [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) to split a PDF file, but I'm having some problem to calculate the size of each page.

The PDF has a size of 170139:

```
22/06/2017  10:14    <DIR>          .
22/06/2017  10:14    <DIR>          ..
22/06/2017  08:36         1.194.504 PDF-01PAG.pdf
22/06/2017  10:10        11.333.168 PDF-12PAG.pdf
21/06/2017  15:53         1.218.918 PDF-13PAG.pdf
22/06/2017  10:13           170.139 PDF-28PAG.pdf
               4 files      13.916.729 bytes
               2 folder     94.124.666.880 bytes
```

The generated PDF has a size of 61082:

```
22/06/2017  10:20    <DIR>          .
22/06/2017  10:20    <DIR>          ..
22/06/2017  10:31            61.082 PDF-28PAG-p0001.pdf
               1 files(s)         61.082 bytes
               2 folder(s)        94.122.778.624 bytes
```

How can I calculate the size of each page from PDF correctly without writing/using file (`File#length()`)?

Here is the test:

```
@Test
public void testCalculatePDF28P() {
    long result = test.calculate(getResorce("PDF/PDF-28PAG.pdf"));
    Assert.assertEquals(170139L, result);
}

@Test
public void testCalculatePDPage()
    throws IOException {
    InputStream resorce = getResorce("PDF/PDF-28PAG.pdf");
    try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(resorce)) {
        PDPage page = document.getPage(0);
        long result = test.calculate(page.getContents());
        File file = new File("PDF/PDF-28PAG.pdf");
        new PDFPage(file, page, 0).writeTo(output);
        Assert.assertEquals(61082L, result);
    }
}
```

Here is the calculator:

```
    public final class SizeCalculator {

        public long calculate(
            final InputStream input) {
            try {
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                int count;
                while ((count = input.read(bytes)) > 0) {
                    out.write(bytes, 0, count);
                }
                return out.size();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please be aware that many products processing PDFs encode some things differently in their outputs. This may result in big differences. Thus, there is no hard value for the size of a page.

Answer (score 1):

anyway,

used it:

```
            PDDocument documentoSaida = new PDDocument();
            for (int i = startPage; i < endPage; i++) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                PDDocument tempFile = new PDDocument();
                PDPage page = document.getPage(i);
                tempFile.addPage(page);
                tempFile.save(baos);
                p(i + ": " + (baos.size() / 1024) + "KB");
                tempFile.close();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on your initial answer, here's a fuller segment:

```
static void printPagesInKB(PDDocument document, int startPage, int endPage) {
    PDDocument tempFile = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
    for (int i = startPage; i < endPage; i++) {
        try {
            baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            tempFile = new PDDocument();
            PDPage page = document.getPage(i);
            tempFile.addPage(page);
            tempFile.save(baos);
            System.out.println("Page " + i + ": " + (baos.size() / 1024) + "KB");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                tempFile.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                baos.flush();
                baos.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Differences:

- Requesting startPage and endPage via variables
- Properly closing opened resources
- Fixed document variable